# Colored logs in IntelliJ with logback custom pattern in yaml configuration of Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, logging, colors, logback

Running a SpringBoot application with the default logback pattern configuration shows colored logs:

[image: intellij colors]

But when introducing a custom pattern in `main.yaml` configuration like:

```
logging:
  pattern:
    console: "%date %thread %level [%logger{10}:%line] %method | %msg%n"
```

Colors in logs are gone:

[image]

How to maintain colored when changing logback pattern?

Answer (score 2):

Adding tag `withJansi` you should have the desired effect.

```xml
<configuration debug="true">
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <withJansi>true</withJansi>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>[%thread] %highlight(%-5level) %cyan(%logger{15}) - %msg %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Result:

[image: intellij console]

Answer (score 0):

Checking logback documentation on [layouts | colouring](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#coloring) section explains how to use colors grouping by parentheses.

So tried this pattern configuration:

```
logging:
  pattern:
    console: "%date %thread %green(%level) [%cyan(%logger{10}):%magenta(%line)] %red(%method) | %msg%n"
```

Final result:
[image]